# Variable web link in python

Tags: python, html, hyperlink

I have what is hopefully an easy question for you.  It involves adding a variable to an "a href" in python.  I am generating files with names that will vary depending on the output of other functions.  I am trying to just add a link to a web page that allows someone to click and download the zip file.

```
import os, sys
path = "C:/output/"
file = "bob.zip"
movedZip = (path + file)

print """<h3><a href=movedZip>Download zip file</a></h3>"""
```

The problem is that on the webpage, the link shows as "localhost/movedZip".  I have tried several iterations of this, but nothing seems to allow the link to be variable.

Thank you for your time, in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I notice that your question is related to the fundamental  operation of Python, and not really HTML or hyperlinks. You might want to review [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) or [The Python3 Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/). For this specific issue, pay attention to the section on [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

Comment: Except that the simple string replacement isn't working here.  There's something else at work that isn't being considered.

Comment: If something else is going on, it is going on *outside* of what you've shown so far. Please provide another short, complete program that demonstrates your new problem.

Comment: The script receives two variables from a previous web page.  From those variables, the code determines which images are desired.  It sends those images to a temp folder, zips up that folder and places it in an output folder for pickup.  That's where things go south.  I'm trying to allow the webpage to provide a button for the user to click on and download the zip file.  Because the zip file's name needs to change based on the variables the script receives, I cannot just make a generic link to the zip file.

Comment: Using print """<h3><a href="%s">Download zip file</a></h3>""" % movedZip, Firebug indicates <a href="None">Download zip file</a>, which it shouldn't given the basic string replacement, right?

Comment: @DanielRoseman asked me to post this in a new question, so I'm doing so now.  I didn't want you to respond here with something similar.  :-) Thank you for your assistance to this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple variable substitution, and doesn't really have anything to do with HREFs. You just need to tell Python to insert the value of your variable into your string.

```
"""<h3><a href="%s">Download zip file</a></h3>""" % movedZip
```

or

```
"""<h3><a href="{}">Download zip file</a></h3>""".format(movedZip)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  print """<h3><a href="%s">Download zip file</a></h3>""" % movedZip is returning a localhost/None.  I get the same result with the second option.  Could there be another aspect to this I'm unaware of?

Comment: Not really, unless there's more code you're not showing us. How are you running this code? Where are you seeing the output?

Comment: The script receives two variables from a previous web page.  From those variables, the code determines which images are desired.  It sends those images to a temp folder, zips up that folder and places it in an output folder for pickup.  That's where things go south.  I'm trying to allow the webpage to provide a button for the user to click on and download the zip file.  Because the zip file's name needs to change based on the variables the script receives, I cannot just make a generic link to the zip file.  Using your code, Firebug indicates <a href="None">Download zip file</a>.

Comment: Well, then sounds like the problem is with the variables being passed in. You should show your actual code that gets those variables, preferably in a new question.